# Test nodejs using postman: How to get req.user in postman

Tags: node.js, testing, postman

I'm using passport for register & login function. My API is like this:

```
router.post('/secret', ctr);
(req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How to test this API using postman?

Comment: Please edit your post to be more clear, are you asking how to send in the "user" field with your post request in Postman?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. First refer to the postman [documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests).

If what you are trying to achieve is to send in the "user" field properly then in Postman set the method to `POST`, and `Content-Type` to `application/json` and send in a valid JSON body with a "user" field in it with your request.

Your Node app should have [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) installed as well.

Comment: thanks for the postman document link. I think postman cookies may help.